# glOrtho do not display a Triangle

Tags: windows, opengl, graphics, projection

triangle is not drawn when glOrtho z range between 0 and 1.

```
glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho( -1,1,-1,1,-1,1 );

glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
glLoadIdentity();
// Draw a triagnle in z 0.5
glBegin( GL_TRIANGLES );
glColor3f( 1, 0, 0 );
glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5, 0.5 );
glVertex3f( 0.5, -0.5, 0.5 );
glVertex3f( 0.0, 0.5, 0.5 );
glEnd();
```

It displays a red triangle. Its fine for me.

But when I change near clipping plane to 0, It displays nothing.
Triangle is drawing with z 0.5, and near and far is between 0 and 1.
But Triangle is not drawn why ?

Following code is used to display the Triangle in z 0.5

```
glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
glLoadIdentity();
glOrtho( -1,1,-1,1,0,1 );


glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
glLoadIdentity();


// Draw a triagnle in z 0.5 This triangle is not displayed.
glBegin( GL_TRIANGLES );
glColor3f( 1, 0, 0 );
glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5, 0.5 );
glVertex3f( 0.5, -0.5, 0.5 );
glVertex3f( 0.0, 0.5, 0.5 );
glEnd();
```

Answer (score 1):

Note that your triangle is being drawn BEHIND the camera. The **positive Z direction is backward**, toward the screen, and the **negative Z direction is forward**, toward the far plane. However, in `glOrtho`, the near and far planes are only **distances in front of the camera**, not actual Z coordinates.

In your first example, the near plane is -1, and the far plane is 1, so the frustum has a range of -1 unit in front of the camera (1 unit behind) to 1 unit in front of the camera. **(from 1 behind to 1 in front)** Therefore, your object behind the camera was drawn.

In your second example, the near plane is 0 units in front of the camera, and the far plane is 1 unit in front of the camera **(from origin to 1 in front)**, so your object behind the camera was not drawn.

To fix it, you should change your triangle to be drawn in front of the camera **by drawing it at -0.5 z instead**.

```
// Setup ortho projection from the origin.
glOrtho( -1,1,-1,1,0,1 );

...

// Draw a triangle in front of the camera, at -0.5 z
glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5, -0.5 );
glVertex3f( 0.5, -0.5, -0.5 );
glVertex3f( 0.0, 0.5, -0.5 );
```

There are also other methods such as **reversing the Z axis**, if you prefer to use positive Z values to represent forward:

```
// Setup ortho projection from the origin, with the Z axis reversed.
// (the far plane is behind the near plane.)
glOrtho( -1,1,-1,1,0,-1 );

...

// Draw a triangle at 0.5 z
glVertex3f( -0.5, -0.5, 0.5 );
glVertex3f( 0.5, -0.5, 0.5 );
glVertex3f( 0.0, 0.5, 0.5 );
```

Answer (score 0):

The `nearVal` and `farVal` values do **not** specify the z values of the clipping planes, but the distance from the camera. In fixed-function OpenGL, eye space is defined with camera at origin, looking at **-z** direction.

[`glOrtho()`](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man2/xhtml/glOrtho.xml) is just defined so that positive values refer to positions in front of the viewer (so it is consistent to the behavior of `glFrustum()`), and negative vaules are behind the viewer, so actually, the planes are at `z=-nearVal` and `z=-farVal` in eye space.

Comment: Hello, Please help me, If I set glOrtho( -1,1,-1,1,0,1 ), then what should be the minimum and maximum of z value of the vertex, to display that vertex in scene.

Comment: Just use (-1.0, 0.0) or (0.0, -1.0), depending ot what handedness of the coordinate system you want/prefer.

Comment: How can i display an object with z value 0.5 with glortho( -1, 1, -1, 1, 0, 1 ).

Comment: Just use (-1.0, 0.0) or (0.0, -1.0), depending ot what handedness of the coordinate system you want/prefer. Here I set zNear as 0, and zFar as 1. How (-1.0,0 ) and ( 0,-1) is related to these zvalues. Please help.

Comment: @user1910317: Let me clarify this. With your above glOrtoh(...,0,1) call, you  specify the near plane at z=0 and the far plane at z=-1. so, to show your triangle, you should draw it somewhere inbetween, e.g. at z=-0.5

Comment: Sorry for asking again.. Then what is the difference between glortho(....-1, 1) and glortho(0,1). I'm trying to create an app which will display the projection information in the screen.. The viewing volume of the projection and the object within the viewing volume.

Comment: @user1910317: as I already said in the answer, that would define near at z-1 and far at z=-1, so that z=0.5 will fall into the frustum and the z range range [-1,1] is visible. With glOrtho(..,0,1), only the z range of [-1,0] will be covered. That is why your triangle at z=0.5 is disappearing in the second case.